# Trying to figure out how to display calculated results by quarter

Tags: sql, oracle

Hey I'm trying to figure this problem that's proving to be difficult. So I have a database which has a Payroll table that shows an employee's weekly wage throughout the year. I'm trying to create a View that shows the Unemployment Insurance contribution the employer pays on a employee's salary for each quarter of the year. The employer pays UI only on the employee's first $15000 earnings. So for example, if the employee earns $20000 in the first quarter, then the employer would only pay the UI rate * 15000 for the first quarter; the remaining $5000 is exempt and the employer pays no UI for the remaining quarters, so the values there would be 0. If the employee earned less than $15000, the UI rate is applied to the whole amount until they earn $15000 (by adding up their earnings for each quarter). So for example if an employee earned $9000 in Q1, $3000 in Q2 and then $4000 in Q3, the employer would pay UI on the whole $9000, then the whole $3000 but in Q3, only on the difference, so since the employee earned $16000 by Q3, the employer would pay UI on $1000 (diff between $16000 and $15000).

[Here is a testview showing the employee and their salary for the 1st quarter. So John Souza and Will Pauly, having earned more than $20000 for the 1st quarter, would just have UI applied to the first $15000 they earned for that 1st quarter and then no UI for the subsequent quarters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cq4o2.png)

So the actual view should look like:

Employee_Name UIQ1 UIQ2 UIQ3 UIQ4

(value)            #     #     #     #

[This is a snippet of the table showing some of employee Tim Sariol's earnings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D1Rlx.png)

This is some code I've been trying to run

```
Create or replace view v6Team4 ("Employee Name", "UI Q1") AS
Select employeename, uiq1 = (case when sum(wage) > 15000 then uiq1 = 0.0156 
* 15000 else uiq1 = select 0.0156 * sum(wage) from payroll
where paydate >= '01/01/2018' and paydate <= '03/31/2018' and sum(wage))
from payroll
group by employeename;
```

I tried doing it with UIQ1 as a start and I know this is wrong but I'm lost. I figure some sort of control flow statement is needed, but I'm not sure how to integrate that with nested select statements, if those are needed at all (and I think they are). If someone could nudge me in the right direction, I would greatly appreciate it. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: latest oracle sql developer

Comment: My solution for this would involve groupby year and month/4 as an inner query, and a subsequent running total going back to year start using sum(quarter earnings) over (partition by employeee, year order by year, quarter rows unbounded preceding) as an outer query, to give the earnings each quarter summed so a calc could be done on whether it had gone over the 15k. I haven’t time to write a solve now, but I’m sure someone will.. maybe this info will be helpful if it takes a while for someone to get to it and you want to have a crack :)

Comment: Oh, and a pivot as an outer outer query, as the last step to turn 4 rows per year employee into a single row of 4 columns per year employee

Comment: thank you so much, I'll get started with that!

Comment: In many Databases, you can also make use of the GREATEST/LEAST function. So, LEAST (salary, 15000) will equal either salary if it is less than 15000 or exactly 15000 if salary exceeds that. This can help you improve the readability of your query

Answer (score 0):

Avoid posting screenshots of your data; no-one will have any desire to type all the data in just to check their query works, and you might be left with only cavalier types like me who are willing to bang a query into SO and say "here; this is probably most the way there but isn't tested; good luck!"

Here, this is most the way there but isn't tested; good luck:

```
SELECT
    EMPLOYEENAME,
    yr,
    SUM(CASE WHEN qtr = 1 THEN taxamt END) as q1,
    SUM(CASE WHEN qtr = 2 THEN taxamt END) as q2,
    SUM(CASE WHEN qtr = 3 THEN taxamt END) as q3,
    SUM(CASE WHEN qtr = 4 THEN taxamt END) as q4
FROM
(
    SELECT
        EMPLOYEENAME,
        yr,
        qtr,
        CASE 
          WHEN payytd <= 15000 THEN payqtr  * 0.2 --fully taxable amounts
          WHEN payytd - 15000 BETWEEN 0 AND payqtr THEN (payqtr - (payytd - 15000)) * 0.2 --partly taxable amounts
          ELSE 0 --nontaxable amounts
        END as taxamt
    FROM
    (
        SELECT
            EMPLOYEENAME,
            yr,
            qtr,
            payqtr,
            SUM(payqtr) OVER(PARTITION BY EMPLOYEENAME, yr, qtr ORDER BY yr, qtr ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) as payytd
        FROM
        ( 
            SELECT 
               EMPLOYEENAME,
               EXTRACT(year FROM paydate) a yr,
               TRUNC((EXTRACT(month FROM paydate) - 1) / 3) + 1 as qtr,
               SUM(wage) as payqtr
            FROM PAYROLL
            GROUP BY EMPLOYEENAME, EXTRACT(year FROM paydate), TRUNC((EXTRACT(month FROM paydate) - 1) / 3) + 1
        ) qtrs
    ) with_ytd
) with_tax
GROUP BY EMPLOYEENAME, yr
```

For debugging advice, I recommend you run each subquery in isolation and check it is returning the results. I could have made efforts to collapse some of these subqueries together but the optimizer will do that, and spread out like this it's hopefully easy to see what we're trying to achieve

The queries in order do;

Group all the pays up into quarters per employee so we should get one quarter/year per em and the sum of their pays

Add a column that sums the quarterly pay back (order by date ascending, consider all preceding rows in the partition) to the start of the employee/year (the partition)

Do some logic on the ytd pay; if it's less than 15k, the whole lot must be taxable. If it's more than 15k (implied) and the remainder of ytd - 15k (the tax free amount) is between 0 and the pay this quarter, then only part of the quarter pay is taxable so subtract the tax free amount from the pay and tax the rest. If the ytd - 15k is more than the pay this quarter then some other quarter was partly taxed with the residue of the tax free allowance and this quarter must be fully tax free

We should now have a list of employees, years, quarters and taxamounts. Use the standard pivot pattern to turn it into a set of years and employees with conditional summation deciding whether a tax amount shall be included in a q1/2/3/4 column

E&OE

Comment: Thank you so much! i just posted the screenshots for context; certainly wasn't expecting anyone to recreate the table just to test the query.